# Twig custom filter not recognized

Tags: symfony, filter, twig

I am trying to create a filter that will convert an Array to a String.

**The error**

```
The filter "toString" does not exist in FooBarMainBundle:Page:News.html.twig at line 15
```

So far I have the following, mainly followed the official documentation, but during render the filter can not be found.

**app/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    foobar_main.twig.main_extension:
        class: FooBar\MainBundle\Twig\MainExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**src/FooBar/MainBundle/Twig/MainExtension.php**

```
<?php
namespace FooBar\MainBundle\Twig;

class MainExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'toString' => new \Twig_SimpleFilter('toString', array($this, 'toString'))
        );
    }

    public function toString($data)
    {
        return implode(", ", $data);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'main_extension';
    }
}
```

**the Twig template**

```
{% createphp cmfMainContent as="rdf" %}
<div {{ createphp_attributes(rdf) }}>
    {% set tags = createphp_content( rdf.tags ) %}
    <h5 {{ createphp_attributes( rdf.tags ) }}>{{ tags|toString }}</h5>
</div>
{% endcreatephp %}
```

Comment: did you clear your cache?

Comment: @nifr, Yes, I did, no luck tho.

Comment: check the service is correctly loaded by `php app/console container:debug|grep 'foobar_main.twig.main_extension'`